# Get Facebook user's name fram DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

The following was described to me as a solution to my problem:

> In the fulfillment code, parse the parameter of fulfillment request and retrieve the value of originalDetectIntentRequest JSON field. For more information about OriginalDetectIntentRequest.

However, I don't know where to start in actually implementing this. What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get things like the user's first_name from DialogFlow. To do that first you need to get the PSID from DialogFlow webhook JSON:

```
PSID = originalDetectIntentRequest -> payload -> data -> sender -> id
```

Then you need to make a post request to FB Graph for Retrieving a Person's Profile.

Something like this:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/<PSID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

You can find more details about getting messenger user's data in:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/#fields